# I need to migrate to NativeScript with WebPack 4

Tags: webpack, nativescript, nativescript-cli

I try to migrate to last NS version @nativescript/core@8.1.5 with nativescript-cli@8.1.4 and migrate my webpack.config.json to WebPack 5 is so difficult.

I try to migrate to nativescript-cli@8.0.2 (11-4-2021) with @nativescript/core@8.0.11 previous a new era with WP 5 but project fail with WP-cli:

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--env.hmr'
```

I try to create a HelloWorld project with:

- nativescript-cli@7.2.1 (11-3-2021)
- Node 14.16.0 (23-2-2021)
- NPM 6.14.11

And the project generate a package.json with:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.1.1",

"devDependencies": {
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.0",
```

And when i run the project fails with:

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--env.hmr'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
Executing webpack failed with exit code 2.
```

When I expected a project to be created with:

- @nativescript/core@7.3.0" (27-2-2021)
- @nativescript/webpack@4

Comment: I've got the same problem. Do you find a solution for that issue?

Comment: Same question, any progress?

Comment: FYI: I've asked, inside the official svelte-native issues channel https://github.com/halfnelson/svelte-native/issues/284, how it's possible to upgrade the version.